# Linq Join on Table with Custom List Issue?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple a join that I want to do but it's not compilng:

```
    private IEnumerable<decimal> GetSampleListOfIds()
    {
        var samplelList = new List<decimal>
        {
            100200m,
            200200m,
            300200m,
            400200m,
            500200m,
            600200m,
            700200m,
            800200m,
            900200m,
            1000200m,
            1100200m,
            1200200m,
            1300200m,
            1400200m,
            1500200m,
            1600200m,
            1700200m,
            1800200m,
            1900200m,
            2000200m,
        };
        return samplelList;
    }
}

    [Test]
    public void TestGetIds()
    {
        var listOfClientIds = GetSampleListOfIds();

        var resultSet = from c in _container.ClientIDs
                        join l in listOfClientIds on c.ClientGUID == l
                        select c.[some useful attribute]
    }
```

That's basically the gist of it, but its no compiling on 'l' and c.ClientGUID is a nullable type. I tried the obvious stuff, but l is not being recognized a decimal type object from listOfClientIds list.

Do i need to use the into keyword, I have done stuff similar to this before but this has really thrown me off.

Can you anyone solve this compilation error? I bet I have missed or done something stupid.

Comment: ur comparing c.ClientGUID with IEnumerable<decimal>??

Comment: What type `c.ClientGUID` has? And what is error message?

Comment: c.ClientGUID is a list of nullable decimal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var resultSet = from c in _container.ClientID
                join l in listOfClientIds on c.ClientGUID equals l
                select c.[some useful attribute]
```

> The join clause compares the specified keys for equality by using the
>   special equals keyword.
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb311040.aspx)

You can also do it without using join:

```
var resultSet = from c in _container.ClientID
                where listOfClientIds.Contains(c.ClientGUID)
                select c.[some useful attribute]
```

Comment: It was another case of 'equals' and '=='. Thanks mate its been a while.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultSet = from c in _container.ClientID
                where listOfClientIds.Any(l => c.ClientGUID.Contains(l))
                select c.[some useful attribute];
```

NOTE: I suggest you to improve naming - `ClientID` looks like single value holding client ID (at least not sequence of ids). `ClientGUID` also looks like single value of `Guid` type. I would expect `Clients` and `Ids` instead.